# What are the numbers appended to included js / css files?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm trying to understand why websites do the following with css and js files - or if / why I'd want to do the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" property="stylesheet" href="/foo/static/css/bar-c0b40.css" type="text/css">
```

Are these auto-generated-looking numbers just for versioning purposes? Or is there some security-related reason to add these?

It seems more brittle to me to have to go in and update these when you update your css library. And more annoying than using the actual version number.

Comment: This is a case of "you're going to have to ask them, not us", since every website is free to use whatever software they please, and then put their own needs on top of those, so _who knows_ what the numbers represent, without knowing which web stack they're using, and what their policy guidelines on assets are? Some systems auto-suffix for cache busting purposes, others for versioning, others still for seemingly no good reason, so...step 1: find out what exact technology is involved, then step 2: read up on that technology.

Comment: `It seems more brittle to me to have to go in and update these when you update your css library.` what makes you think you have to update them manually? If you can generate the file, you should be able to inject it automatically.

Comment: My guess is that's a hash for cache-busting.

Comment: We use them for cache busting and our build process auto-injects the correct filenames.

Comment: welcome to web development in 2018

Answer (score 0):

I think it is used to eliminate any chance for outdated css files to be loaded from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Is a special feature of webpack that is commonly used by newest frameworks like Angular, React, Vue, etc. I mean is used to prevent the browser cache. But the file is updated, only if is necessary.

In fact is a tool.